# Meteor links do not work without 'www' prefix

Tags: meteor, heroku, routes, iron-router

I have a Meteor web application hosted by Heroku. I use Iron Router for the routing layer. I am able to navigate to the homepage, assigned to the `/` route, without using the `www` prefix in the URL. However, navigating to any other route by typing the url in the address bar without using the `www` prefix will just redirect to the homepage. Internal site links using iron-router's `pathFor` work fine.

EDIT: I found this exact same issue on the serverfault community: https://serverfault.com/questions/617248/does-google-domains-support-cname-like-functionality-at-the-zone-apex

No immediate solution was provided there either. I'm investigating CloudFlare as an option.

Comment: Are you using pathFor while generating urls?

Comment: If I'm not wrong, this could be solved by proxy configuration in your server, not with Meteor codes.

Comment: @Tdm, yes, but internal links using pathFor work fine. It's only a problem when I directly type a url into my browser's address bar.

Comment: @Luna, how can I do that? Like I said, I can navigate to the website without the prefix, but it always directs me to the hompage no matter what url I enter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

David, I have an idea which is not for a straight Meteor solution, but maybe this will let you solve your problem.

Go to your domain configuration at your domain provider panel. Create redirect of the *www* address to non-*www* address of your website. As long as I have same site displayed on both addresses I always do it this way, and it works like a charm.

Keep in mind your domain propagation time (6-36 hours).

Comment: I have a subdomain forward of the non-www address to the www address. Are you saying I should reverse that forward?

Comment: My hosting provider (Google Domains), does not seem to let me do that. I get an error message "Conflicts with existing records on: www"

Comment: You have to remove old record first (or change its content).